# Mixed Content Error On Socket.io Chat App

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, https, socket.io

So I have a socket.io chat app witch worked fine on my pc however, when I publish the frontend on github pages and the backend using Replit it says mixed content error, how can I fix it?[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uAA1.jpg)

Comment: your page is served over HTTPS, but the script you're including points to an HTTP resource.

Comment: make it point to the HTTPS version: `https://chat-socket.sx9.repl.co/socket.io/socket.io.js`

Comment: You can elaborate more on it.